# Class error handling not visible in output

Tags: python, error-handling

I was trying to add exceptions and in my class but it does not give me any error but also does not give me any output when I enter the wrong values in. It gives me the default errors when I use Python. Please note this is only as snipped of my class and not the entire code. I am happy to share the remaining code but I think the relevant is only needed.

```
class FairDetect():
    def __init__(self, model,X_test,y_test):
        self.model = model
        self.X_test = X_test
        self.y_test = y_test

    def create_labels(self):
        sensitive_label = {}
        for i in set(self.X_test[sensitive]):
            try:
                text = "Please Enter Label for Group" +" "+ str(i)+": "
                label = input(text)
                sensitive_label[i]=label
            except ValueError:
                print("This is not the right value")
        return(sensitive_label)
```

This are the values that the user needs to define but it somehow does not give me the expected output nor do I get an error when I run the class.

```
sensitive = 'group' # sensible variable one wants to test for biases
labels = {0:'GROUP A',1:'GROUP B'} # 0 - GROUP A and 1 - GROUP B Because we dont know yet what Group is referring to
fd.identify_bias('group',labels)
```

The error that I get is a key error value because I entered on purpose a wrong value.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You might want to clean this up a bit, first. It gives errors because of the typos, missing data, or missing code, but not the one you wanted to ask about. Also, it's going to be hard to test a function with side effects. Provide the input as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This would be example of input parameters:
sensitive = 'Group' #
labels = {0:'GROUP A',1:'GROUP B'} # 
fd.understand_shap(labels,'Group',1,0)

Comment: if fd an instance of FairDetect? Is the error supposed to happen when you call identify_bias or create_labels? Or this other new function you never mentioned before, understand_shap? What are X_test and Y_test? Is the question about raising an exception (which you didn't do)?